# How to prove the residue field at the point $x \in \text{Spec} \, k[X]$ is $k$, when $X$ is affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The residue field $k(x)$ at a point $x$ in Spec $A$ is defined to the field of fractions of the quotient ring, $A/x$.

This may be easy, but I'm really stuck with proving $k(x) = k$.

Edit: Failed to mention earlier, $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: It might not be, if $x$ is not a closed point.

Comment: It's not true that $k(x) = k$ without further conditions on $k$, even for closed points.  For instance, take $(x^2+1) \in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$.  I suspect you want to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.  In this case, it should follow from the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Yes, $k$ is supposed to be algebraically closed. How does it follow from the Nullstellensatz? @Quasicoherent

Comment: Can you show that $k(x)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra?  Then the Nullstellensatz implies that it's actually a finitely generated $k$-module, i.e., an algebraic extension of $k$.  (See [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FS).)  Then use the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed.